# Connect Error (1044) Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mysqli

I have a site on WordPress, and I need to execute one PHP file on it but I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'topimobiliare_ad'@'localhost' to database 'topimobilare' in /home/topimobiliare/public_html/create_feed_cron_job.php on line 11
>      Connect Error (1044) Access denied for user 'topimobiliare_ad'@'localhost' to database 'topimobilare'

Login, pass, server and db_name are from the `wp_config.php` file. I don't know what's wrong.

Connection code:

```
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="topimobiliare_ad";
$dbpassword="hidden";
$dbname="topimobilare";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: It means that one of your details is wrong. Some hosting services put names before the database and the username to avoid people connecting easily.

Comment: Your username/password/host combination is incorrect. Make sure that the user `'topimobiliare_ad'@'localhost'` exists, and the password is correct.

Comment: It's impossible... username/password/host  are from wp_config.php but wp site works well..

Comment: There are only so many things that can be wrong.  Username, password, access to DB and host.  Is the DB on the same host as the PHP file?

Comment: Yes... php file is on root folder
**/home/topimobiliare/public_html/create_feed_cron_job.php**

Answer (score 0):

There is two possibility.

1). The user does not exist.

2). Second is user grant issue.

If the user has any grant related issue then you can give grant as per following.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Please check this file is available in your server **http://phpmyadmin.yourdomain.com/server_privileges.php**
If not then you do not have the privileges permission.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Paresh Barad

If your 1. hostname/servername, 2. dbname, 3. username and 4. password are okay

Then the connect error (1044) might be caused by a privilages related issue

Solution:

1. Add the user (top_imobilare_ad) to the database (topimobilare)
   [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGgWp.png)
2. Give that user the privilages they need and click on 'Make changes'
   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7QkJ.png)

3. Retry the link